# Gulp build formatError - gulp + harpjs + gulp-gh-page + node

Tags: javascript, html, debugging, gulp, harp

I'm working on a project based on :

https://github.com/superhighfives/charliegleason.com

Everything was working so great, and now i have a problem when i try to build the project using gulp build ...

The link to the img of the term error:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/YU4oc.png

> Error: 1
>     at formatError (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/gulp/bin/gulp.js:169:10)
>
> at Gulp. (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/gulp/bin/gulp.js:195:15)
>
> at Gulp.emit (events.js:107:17)
>
> at Gulp.Orchestrator._emitTaskDone (/Users/qvoiriot/Documents/qvoiriot.github.io/node_modules/gulp/node_modules/orchestrator/index.js:264:8)
>     at /Users/qvoiriot/Documents/qvoiriot.github.io/node_modules/gulp/node_modules/orchestrator/index.js:275:23
>
> at finish (/Users/qvoiriot/Documents/qvoiriot.github.io/node_modules/gulp/node_modules/orchestrator/lib/runTask.js:21:8)
>
> at ChildProcess.cb (/Users/qvoiriot/Documents/qvoiriot.github.io/node_modules/gulp/node_modules/orchestrator/lib/runTask.js:29:3)
>
> at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:129:20)
>
> at maybeClose (child_process.js:1015:16)
>
> at Socket. (child_process.js:1183:11)
>
> at Socket.emit (events.js:107:17)
>
> at Pipe.close (net.js:485:12)

The build process is the same that you can see in the link below. For the build part :

```
gulp.task('build', function (done) {
  cp.exec('harp compile . dist', {stdio: 'inherit'})
    .on('close', done)
});
```

If anybody have an idea about the way i can fix this ... ???

Thanks,

Q

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same error with a [Gulp/Harp](https://github.com/ianrose/storysettings) setup after installing [nvm](https://github.com/creationix/nvm). I fixed it by re-installing [Harp.js](http://harpjs.com/docs/quick-start) globally.

```
npm install -g harp
```